# PROC SQL Where Condition

Tags: sas

I'm attempting to remove a number of records where the REASON_FOR_VISIT variable string ranges from psych to asthma issues and KEEP patients who have an acuity of 3. However, when I run this code and do a proc freq of REASON_FOR_VISIT I still get results that contain the key words of records I want to remove.

```
proc sql;
create table NoPysch as
Select *
from ED_TAT
Where 
    Pt_Acuity like '%3%'
    AND TRACK_Group like '%ED Tracking%'
    AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%asth%' 
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%asthma%' 
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%asthma/%' 
    AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%suicidal%' 
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%assualt%' 
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%assult%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%APA%' 
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%legal%'  
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%suicide%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like 'ASA'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '/ASA'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%SI/%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%SI, attempt%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%SI w%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like 'SI'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like 'HI'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%homicide%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%psyc%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%psch%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%FD-12%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%behavior%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%behav%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%overdose%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%agitation%'
    AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%aggression%'
AND REASON_FOR_VISIT not like '%psy eval%';
run; 

proc freq data=NoPysch;
table REASON_FOR_VISIT;
run;
```

Comment: what are the values not getting filtered ?  SAS SQL is case sensitive.

Comment: ah that would explain it, I think. Let me try to alter the cases-thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than pollute your code with the filtering criteria, consider putting the like targets in a separate lookup table.  One form of checking a value for presence or not presence in a lookup table is called an existential sub-select.

Most of the targets are of a 'containing' nature, as specified by `%<target>%`, and some do not have wildcards, such as `'SI'`, `'HI'`, which would have to match exactly in order to be filtered.

If all the items are really a 'containing' type of match, just specify the target values in the lookup table and add the bracketing `%` to the code in the sub-select query.  If you want to have all the varieties of like matches (starts with `<target>%`, ends with `%<target>` or contains `%<target>%` the lookup targets will need to include the wildcards.

For example, the existential query checks **all** the reason filters because of the **NOT EXISTS**.  If no filter expression matches the reason, the record will be selected.

```
data reason_like_filter;
input; 
expression = _infile_;
datalines4;
%asth%
%asthma%
%asthma/%
%suicidal%
%assualt%
%assult%
%APA% 
%legal%  
%suicide%
ASA
/ASA
%SI/%
%SI, attempt%
%SI w%
SI
HI
%homicide%
%psyc%
%psch%
%FD-12%
%behavior%
%behav%
%overdose%
%agitation%
%aggression%
%psy eval%
;;;;

data ed_tat;
  pt_acuity = 'AABB3DDEE';
  track_group = 'Regional ED Tracking base';
  length pid 8 reason_for_visit $50;
  input pid reason_for_visit;
  infile cards dsd dlm=',';
datalines;
1, "Suicide"
2, "Suicidal"
3, "Psy eval mm//dd/yy"
4, "Drop off cookies"
5, "Visit friend"
6, "Heart attack"
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select * 
  , (
select count(*)
      from reason_like_filter FILTER
      where upcase(REASON_FOR_VISIT) LIKE upcase(FILTER.expression)
) as N

  from ED_TAT
  where 
   Pt_Acuity like '%3%'
   AND TRACK_Group like '%ED Tracking%'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
      select *
      from reason_like_filter FILTER
      where upcase(REASON_FOR_VISIT) LIKE trim(upcase(FILTER.expression))
   )
   ;
quit;
```